# ios ipad tabbar in splitview layout like this image

Tags: ios, layout, uitabbar

i have to make one ipad application like this image , splite view(left and right view). In left side view have a tabbar , how to make this type of layout  [image]

If you have any link please share with me

Answer (score 0):

You should learn SplitViewControllers. Here is the link -

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/SplitViewControllers.html